# Participate in meta privilege

Tags: discussion, support

Why can't I post a question on the meta site even though I earned "Participate in meta privilege"? This is true for all sites. For how many days do these privileges remain valid?

Comment: You posted in meta.

Answer (score 2):

Your reputation is independent on each site. The one exception to that is that, [once you attain 200 rep on any site, all of your accounts receive a 100 point boost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254472/100-reputation-bonus-upon-joining-new-stack-exchange-site).

> Congratulations! One of your linked accounts has reached 200 reputation points, and as a result, all associated accounts are given a 100 point bonus.
>
> The bonus is awarded because you have proven that you know your way around the basic features of any Stack Exchange website, and with those 100 extra points you can now comment, vote, flag and create bounties on all SE sites.

As per [the list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), you only need 5 rep to post in Meta. And, following with your question of how many days they are valid, your privileges remain as long as you maintain that level of rep. If it drops below the threshold, such as through downvotes or bounties, you lose those privileges (I don't know if the 200 rep site bonus will go away).

Comment: you have luc6idly,.answered my question.Thanks a lot user 37⁹9220

Comment: @user37920 :) Not critical, but you can accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark if you think it does properly answer your question.